# R lag time independent variable

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dependent variable with irregular dates(time intervals) of occurrence, and several independent variables with dates for which I want to give a time lag of one year.
The sample independent data looks like this (there are some 5 different datasets):

```
College  District   DateEstablished  Subjects 
1           AA       2001/06/15       Commerce
2           BB       2007/07/29       Arts
3           CC       2005/09/17       Engineering
```

And sample dependent data is as below:

```
District   Date  
AA         2001/08/09
BB         2016/01/10
CC         2009/06/23
```

The data is spread over 16 years. I'm new to data analysis, so I'd appreciate some help on going about this. Thanks!

Comment: it would be helpful if you paste some data so it is reproducible

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: library(zoo) can deal with irregular time series